# Postgres 9.0 linux command to windows command conversion

Tags: linux, command-line, shell-script, windows, postgresql

i am working on an application using `delphi 7` as the front end and `postgres 9.0` as the back end.

I have to upload images to the server so i use `\lo_import` and `\lo_export` for inserting images on the server and geting the images from the server.

i had come across a problem where is needed the `LASTOID` after a `\lo_import` so i can use the OID to update a row in my table but i cant set the syntax correct in windows

here is my question on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786014/postgesql-lo-import-and-how-to-get-the-resulting-oid-into-an-update-command/9786524#comment12459997_9786524).. i have got the answer but the script is in linux sheel command ..i cannot run it in windows

```
         psql -h 192.168.1.12 -p 5432 -d myDB -U my_admin << EOF
         \lo_import '/path/to/my/file/zzz4.jpg'
         UPDATE species
         SET    speciesimages = :LASTOID
         WHERE  species = 'ACAAC04';
         EOF
```

and

```
  echo "\lo_import '/path/to/my/file/zzz4.jpg' \\\\ UPDATE species SET speciesimages =   :LASTOID WHERE  species = 'ACAAC04';" | \
 psql -h 192.168.1.12 -p 5432 -d myDB -U my_admin
```

i have tried this though in windows

```
  "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin\psql.exe" -h 192.168.1.12 -p 5432 -d myDB -U my_admin -c "\lo_import 'C://im/zzz4.jpg'";
```

then immediately (programmatically) im doing

```
    "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin\psql.exe" -h 192.168.1.12 -p 5432 -d nansis -U nansis_admin -c " update species SET speciesimages = :LASTOID WHERE species='ACAAC24'"
```

But i get `Syntax error at or near ":"`

can any1 tell tell me how to covert it to windows commnad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this answer from my question on stackoverflow [postgres-9-0-linux-command-to-windows-command-conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798775/postgres-9-0-linux-command-to-windows-command-conversion/9799941#9799941)

Just put the commands in a file (say import.psql)

```
 -- contents of import.psql
\lo_import '/path/to/my/file/zzz4.jpg'
 UPDATE species
 SET    speciesimages = :LASTOID
 WHERE  species = 'ACAAC04';
```

then issue command

```
 "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.0\bin\psql.exe" -h 192.168.1.12 -p 5432 -d myDB -U my_admin -f import.psql
```